# Cosmo db query stats understand

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Can someone tell me how to read the query stats in cosmo db. I know that each item in cosmo have a hard limit of 2MB, however, the the retrieved document size here is more than 5 MB. So I am confused, is the the correct place to find out the size of an item. Because if it is then what about the hard limit of 2MB
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood the limits , the 2MB [hard limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#per-item-limits) is for the document that you store.

However in this particular sample that you provided , the 5.7MB is the size of total documents that you retrieved. In this case there are 646 documents. You can see the exact definition from the metrics explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-api-query-metrics).

Also, Response Size Quota per Page of Results (default is 4MB, for large query results - Cosmos DB will paginate results, and each page will be limited.

Comment: thank you for explaining, so if i want to see the size of one item that is store, do you know which query i can run?

Comment: you can use the SDK and use the header as explained in the documentation.  headers['x-ms-resource-usage']